# How to copy formatted text from Word document to Rich Text Format email body?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

This macro drafts an email in Rich Text Format. (HTML body is not an option for me in this case.)

I need to populate the body of the email with default text and two attachments placed in the middle of the email. (Path1 and Path2).

I find formatting body text with RTF less intuitive than HTML. Copying the body of the email from a dynamic Word document seems like a good solution.

(I did not write the majority of this code, just trying to improve it for this purpose.)

```vb
Option Explicit
Function send_mail_rich_text(ByVal send_to As String, ByVal 
    mail_subject As String, ByVal mail_content As Range, ByVal 
    cc_list As String)

    Dim oOlApp As Object    ' Outlook.Application
    Dim oOlMItem As Object  ' Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oWdDoc As Object    ' Word.Document
    
    Dim Path1 As String
    Dim Path2 As String
    
    Path1 = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Wallet Allocations 42069xD.xlxs"
    Path2 = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Hash Rate Info.xlsx"
    
    Err.Clear

    Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oOlMItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    ' Range can be copied directly as given as Range via function call
    'mail_content.Copy

    ' On Error Resume Next   ' activate it after debugging
    With oOlMItem
        .To = send_to
        .Subject = mail_subject
        .BodyFormat = 3 ' 3=RichTextFormat

        'Set oWdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor

        ' by this you paste below your signature
        ' oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Paste

        .Display
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        send_mail_rich_text = "error"
    ElseIf oOlMItem.Sent = True Then
        send_mail_rich_text = "sent"
    Else
        send_mail_rich_text = "no error, but not sent"
    End If
End Function

Sub TestSendmailFunction()
    Debug.Print send_mail_rich_text("shiba.inu@DogeCoin.com", "HODL- To the Moon!", ActiveSheet.Range("B2:C3"), "Cheems@reddit.com")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To add attachments you can use the [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method which creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. For example:

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", _ 
 olByValue, 3, "Test" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

The `Position` parameter applies only to email messages using the Rich Text format: it is the position where the attachment should be placed within the body text of the message. A value of 1 for the Position parameter specifies that the attachment should be positioned at the beginning of the message body. A value 'n' greater than the number of characters in the body of the email item specifies that the attachment should be placed at the end. A value of 0 makes the attachment hidden.

To send the email you need to replace the `Display` method with the `Send` one.

Comment: Just to confirm Using the Attachments.Add method will have the attachment display within the body of the email in outlook and not underneath the address row in outlook?

Comment: Line 4 of the sub : Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  Throwing run-time error 438 Object does'nt support this property/method.

Comment: This is a sample code where you can see how attachments are added.

Comment: Just following up here. Would it be best to actually use a macro to populate a word document to create the whole email body (attachments tables charts etc) and then just send the email from VBA in MSWord? I am just having trouble mapping out how/where to go to build this macro.

Comment: Yes, you can use the Word object model to set up the message body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When calling `MailItem.Attachments.Add`, specify the attachment position using the `Position` parameter (parameter number 3). It is a good idea to have `\objattph` RTF placeholder tag placed at that position.

Answer (score 0):

Not apparent why Excel is involved. This code is for Outlook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function send_mail_rich_text(ByVal send_to As String, ByVal mail_subject As String)

    ' This code is for Outlook.
    
    Dim oOlMItem As MailItem
    
    Dim Word As New Word.Application
    Dim oWdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim Doc As String
    Doc = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Test.docx"
    'Sample text for Test.docx
    'Hello Team:
    '
    '
    '
    'Thank You
    
    Dim Path1 As String
    Dim Path2 As String
    
    Path1 = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Wallet Allocations 42069xD.xlxs"
    Path2 = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Hash Rate Info.xlsx"
    
    Set oWdDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Doc, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Word.Selection.WholeStory
    Word.Selection.copy

    oWdDoc.Close
    Word.Quit

    Set oOlMItem = CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
    With oOlMItem
    
        .To = send_to
        .Subject = mail_subject
        .BodyFormat = 3     ' 3=RichTextFormat
        
        Set oWdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        oWdDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
        
        ' Adjust character position 14 and 15 as needed.
        .Attachments.Add Path1, , 14
        .Attachments.Add Path2, , 15
        
        .Display
        
    End With
    
    If oOlMItem.Sent = True Then
        send_mail_rich_text = "sent"
    Else
        send_mail_rich_text = "not sent"
    End If
    
End Function


Sub TestSendmailFunction()
    Debug.Print send_mail_rich_text("someone@somewhere.com", _
      "Word document content and attachments")
End Sub
```

Code not in Outlook

```vb
Option Explicit

Function send_mail_rich_text(ByVal send_to As String, ByVal mail_subject As String)

    ' Late binding.
    ' Reference to Outlook and Word Object libraries not required
    Dim oOlApp As Object    ' Outlook.Application
    Dim oOlMItem As Object  ' Outlook.MailItem
    
    Dim Word As Object      ' Word.Application
    Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    Dim oWdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim Doc As String
    Doc = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Test.docx"
    'Sample text for Test.docx
    'Hello Team:
    '
    '
    '
    'Thank You
    
    Dim Path1 As String
    Dim Path2 As String
    
    Path1 = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Wallet Allocations 42069xD.xlxs"
    Path2 = "C:\Users\DegenTrader\Desktop\Hash Rate Info.xlsx"
    
    Set oWdDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Doc, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Word.Selection.WholeStory
    Word.Selection.Copy

    oWdDoc.Close
    Word.Quit
    
    Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oOlMItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(0)     ' 0 - Mailitem
    
    With oOlMItem
    
        .To = send_to
        .Subject = mail_subject
        .BodyFormat = 3     ' 3=RichTextFormat
        
        Set oWdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        oWdDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
        
        ' Adjust character position 14 and 15 as needed.
        .Attachments.Add Path1, , 14
        .Attachments.Add Path2, , 15
        
        .Display
        
    End With
    
    If oOlMItem.Sent = True Then
        send_mail_rich_text = "sent"
    Else
        send_mail_rich_text = "not sent"
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining that part. For some reason my team has too many issues with Outlook macro security but not excel. Furthermore this macro will eventually need to include specific tables pasted into the email....